# SQL server 2014 Developer Edition

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2014, license

I need a Clarification about Sql server 2014 developer edition licensing.I came to know that,for a Cheap price(50$ or something) developer edition is available.also it is given that multiple users can be connection only requirement is a **developer licence** for user.can anyone please explain me what is developer edition and also with one developer edition can i connect 4 client machienes to one server.?(for demonstation purposes only,so no worry about max db size limit).Kindly help me.

Comment: See Microsoft's simple guidance for  **SQL Server 2014 Developer Edition** at http://www.microsoftstore.com/store/msusa/en_US/pdp/SQL-Server-2014-Developer-Edition/productID.298540400